# How do you pass an F# function into another F# function from C# app?

Tags: f#, class-library, c#-to-f#

I have F# class library assembly that contains two functions:

```
let add a b = a + b
```

and

```
let rec aggregateList list init (op:int -> int -> int) =
    match list with
    |[] -> init
    |head::tail ->
        let rest = aggregateList tail init op
        op rest head
```

I have a C# console application which references the F# library and is attempting to do the following:

```
FSharpList<int> l = new FSharpList<int>(1, new FSharpList<int>(2, FSharpList<int>.Empty));
int result = myFsLibrary.aggregateList(l, 0, myFsLibrary.add);
```

However, the compiler complains that [myFsLibrary.add] cannot be converted from 'method group' to `FSharpFunc<int, FSharpFunc<int, int>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly create a function using the `FSharpFunc` delegate. In C#, it is more convenient to create function that takes all arguments as a tuple, so you can do that and then convert the function to a curried type using `FuncConvert`. Something like:

```
FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled(new FSharpFunc<Tuple<int, int>, int>(args => 
    arags.Item1 + args.Item2))
```

However, if you need to call some F# function from your C# code, it is recommended to expose a function with a C#-friendly interface. In this case, I you can use `Func` delegate and the first argument should be `IEnumerable` instead of F#-specific list type:

```
module List = 
    let AggregateListFriendly inp init (op:Func<int, int, int>) =
        aggregateList (List.ofSeq inp) init (fun a b -> op.Invoke(a, b))
```

Then your C# appplication can just use:

```
List.AggregateListFriendly(Enumerable.Range(0, 10), 0, (a, b) => a + b));
```

Answer (score 9):

Other people have provided answers, but I'll just step in to say that you shouldn't do this.

Don't expose F# lists to C#.  Don't expose curried functions to C#.  The impedance mismatch is visible at this boundary, so it is better to expose common framework types at cross-language assembly boundaries.  See

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf

for more advice.

Comment: Why not? That is one of the recommendations I don't understand. If I want to have the guarantees of immutable collections, is F# List not  the only thing available that conveys immutability in .NET? If one uses IEnumerable, this provides no guarantees on immutability what-so-ever to the client of the library. I only wish FSharpList was an interface...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that add is exported as a normal .Net style function and has the rough signature

```
int add(int, int)
```

C#, and most .Net languages, see this as a method which takes 2 `int` parameters and returns a single `int` value.  F# though doesn't see functions this way.  Instead it sees `add` as a function takes an `int` and returns a function which in turn takse an `int` and returns an `int`.  This view of functions makes it very easy to implement operations like currying.

In order to convert from the C# view of the world to F# you need to do a bit of magic to fold a method onto itself.  I accomplish this by defining a set of F# factory and extension methods to do the magic for me.  For example

```
[<Extension>]
type public FSharpFuncUtil = 

    [<Extension>] 
    static member ToFSharpFunc<'a,'b,'c> (func:System.Func<'a,'b,'c>) = 
        fun x y -> func.Invoke(x,y)

    static member Create<'a,'b,'c> (func:System.Func<'a,'b,'c>) = 
        FSharpFuncUtil.ToFSharpFunc func
```

I can use this library to get the appropriate F# delegate type for the `add` method like so

```
var del = FSharpFuncUtil.Create<int, int, int>(myFsLibrary.add);
```